# SharePoint Online Office 365 Redirect After Delete

Tags: sharepoint-online

When I delete an internal list it's (I assume) going to redirect back to the page I was on. However that is not what happens, I am redirected to a blank page with this:

```
92|pageRedirect|owssvr|https://interneturl.sharepoint.com/path/to/list/allitems.aspx
```

Does anyone have an idea of where I should look to correct this behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for us:

In your masterpage, remove the CDATA tags surrounding this script.

Change this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ var submitHook = function () { return false; }; theForm._spOldSubmit = theForm.submit; theForm.submit = function () { if (!submitHook()) { this._spOldSubmit(); } }; //]]></script>
```

To this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var submitHook = function () { return false; }; theForm._spOldSubmit = theForm.submit; theForm.submit = function () { if (!submitHook()) { this._spOldSubmit(); } }; </script>
```

No need to disable MDS and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen something similar following the creation of a new List View in an on-premise installation. In that case disabling the [Minimum Download Strategy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn456544(v=office.15).aspx) feature for the site caused the issue to go away.

[MDS Caused Error After Modifying List View](http://sharepointmadam.blogspot.com/2013/12/mds-caused-error-after-modifying-list.html)

[SharePoint 2013: pageRedirect fails (owssrv.dll issue)](http://buli.waw.pl/sharepoint-2013-pageredirect-fails-owssrv-issue/)